# How to prove $E(X)E(1/X)\ge1$?

Tags: probability, independence

I am trying to understand why $E(X)E(1/X)\ge1$ holds under following assumptions:

1. $X>0$
2. $E(X)$ exists
3. $E(1/X)$ exists
4. $X$ is a continuous random variable

To begin with, I have a problem with reasoning about random variables' independence. If the variables $1/X$ and $X$ were independent then inequality would hold in accordance with basic properties of expected value. But since $X$ is generally not independent from itself would that imply that is generally not independent from its functions? How to approach reasoning about independence in such cases?

Comment: Independence is irrelevant here; one is only interested in expectations.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you, but why is it irrelevant? Why if I wanted to apply rule $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ that holds if $X$ and $Y$ are independent? To either accept or reject this as an option I would need to understand something about their independence, wouldn't I?

Comment: To answer the question in the title (which is not the question in the body, **and this is bad**), the random variables X and 1/X are not independent except if X is almost surely constant. Rereading the definition of the independence of random variables seems like an urgent task.

Comment: @Did Edited. I am probably missing understanding of it, which is part of the reason for the question. Thank you for helpful answers.

Comment: Let us stay concrete: what is this definition already?

Comment: @Did You want me to quote the definition? $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \sigma(Y)$, $\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}\Pr(X \in A, Y \in B) = \Pr(X \in A) \Pr(Y \in B)$

Comment: I want nothing, actually, I am simply mentioning the obvious, which is that you seemingly never used the definition of independence in what you say your thoughts to solve this were. Or at least, if you did, this does not show. (By the way, your definition of the independence of $X$ and $Y$ is wrong, please (re-)read what $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ mean.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68609/discussion-between-szymon-brych-and-did).

Comment: "Let us continue this discussion in chat" No thanks. Please follow my suggestions and then we might have some meaningful exchanges, but until then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$E(Y^2)E(Z^2)\ge E(YZ)^2$$
applied to $Y=X^{1/2}$ and $Z=X^{-1/2}$.